# Can two threads call a new socket (client socket) in the same port?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, port

What should happen if a Thread instantiates a new client Socket while other Thread is handling another client Socket connected to the same port? This Threads are part of the same Java program.

Comment: could you provide the code for the two different attempts to open a socket? Ordinarily once a local port is in use with a socket it can not be opened with a second socket since it is already in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you asking about client or server socket. But I'll answer both. If you try to open a listening server socket on the same port - you'll get `java.net.BindException thrown: Address already in use (Bind failed)` or something similar. If you are connecting to a port - it works fine if the server accepts multiple clients.

And it does not matter if it is same thread, different thread or another process.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm talking about client sockets, that belongs to the same Java program.

Comment: @abaraza I've answered it too - no matter of threads - it works fine if the server accepts multiple clients.

Answer (score 0):

A [`Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) has two ports – a *local port* and a *remote port*. These are called *source port* and *destination port* in the [TCP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1).

When you connect to a server, you specify the host name and the (remote) port. The server needs to know where to send the responses, which is why the client will also have a (local) port. The local port is assigned by the operating system from the pool of free ports.

Try this code sample:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100 * j);
                    try (Socket socket = new Socket("stackoverflow.com", 80)) {
                        System.out.printf("%d -> %d%n", socket.getLocalPort(), socket.getPort());
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ignored) {}
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of one execution on my machine looks like this:

```
36699 -> 80
36700 -> 80
36701 -> 80
36703 -> 80
36708 -> 80
36709 -> 80
36710 -> 80
36712 -> 80
36713 -> 80
36714 -> 80
```

The local ports will generally vary each time.

In conclusion: The client doesn’t care how many sockets are connected to the same remote address. There won’t be any collision between the local ports, either.

Further reading:

- [Lesson: All About Sockets (The Java™ Tutorials > Custom Networking)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)
- [Java SE 8: Getting Started with Socket Programming](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SocketProgramming/SocketProgram.html)